# SWT Spinner - Hiding Buttons

Tags: java, swt, spinner

Is there any possibility to hide/remove the buttons of the `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Spinner` control without completely reimplementing it?

The easiest way I can think of would be a style-Flag but I was not able to find one which influences the buttons.

Maybe it is not possible at all since the OS manages the implementation of those controls.

Comment: Erm, without the buttons, wouldn't it just be a text field then?

Comment: No, since the Spinner got special properties regarding the validation of its input (min, max, digits). Of course I could manually implement this behavior for a text field but its generally better to use existing functionality. And the Spinner does exactly what I need besides displaying the buttons.

Comment: AFAIK you can't hide the buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source of the `Spinner` class there is no support for leaving out the buttons.

I looked at the Mac, Windows and Linux versions of the source.